# Blogdown posts appearing in RStudio but not on Github Pages

Tags: r, github-pages, hugo, blogdown

I'm trying to deploy a site built in blogdown on Github Pages and running into an issue where some content leads to a 404 in the live version, but works fine when served in RStudio.

The deployed page can be viewed [here](http://dshkol.github.io), and the source for it is viewable on [Github](https://github.com/dshkol/dshkol.github.io).

The page in question is at https://dshkol.github.io/2017/08/30/starting-a-blog/ - opening which produces a 404 error. This page renders fine when launched using `blogdown::serve_site` in RStudio.

Importantly, all other sections of the blogdown page work in both RStudio and on Github Pages. This includes /Projects/, /Contact/, and /About/.

The site uses the Hugo Ghostwriter theme, which is one of the ones recommended in the blogdown documentation.

[image: screenshot]

Relevant(?) sections of the TOML file:

```
baseurl = "https://dshkol.github.io/"
publishDir = "../dshkol.github.io"
title = "dshkol blog"
theme = "ghostwriter"
languageCode = "en-us"
disqusShortname = "dshkol"
googleAnalytics = "XXX"
ignoreFiles = ["\\.Rmd$", "\\.Rmarkdown$", "_files$", "_cache$"]



[Taxonomies]
    tag = "tags"

[Params]
    intro = true
    headline = "DSHKOL"
    description = "Thoughts and words"
    opengraph = true
    shareTwitter = true
    shareFacebook = true
    shareGooglePlus = true
    shareLinkedIn = false
    dateFormat = "Mon, Jan 2, 2006"
    highlightJsUrl = ""
    highlightJsLocalUrl = ""

[Permalinks]
    post = "/:year/:month/:day/:slug/"

[[menu.main]]
    name = "Blog"
    url = "/"
    weight = 1

[[menu.main]]
    name = "Projects"
    url = "/project/"
    weight = 2

[[menu.main]]
    name = "Contact"
    url = "/page/contact/"
    weight = 3

[[menu.main]]
    name = "About"
    url = "/page/about/"
    weight = 4
```

My session info:

```
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/C/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.12    bookdown_0.5    digest_0.6.12   rprojroot_1.2   mime_0.5        backports_1.1.0
 [7] magrittr_1.5    evaluate_0.10.1 blogdown_0.1.3  stringi_1.1.5   rmarkdown_1.6   tools_3.4.1    
[13] servr_0.7       stringr_1.2.0   httpuv_1.3.5    compiler_3.4.1  htmltools_0.3.6 knitr_1.17
```

And relevant Hugo details:

```
> Sys.which('hugo')
hugo 
  "" 
> blogdown:::find_hugo()
[1] "/Users/dshkol/Library/Application Support/Hugo/hugo"
> blogdown::hugo_version()
[1] ‘0.26’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of commit [7da94409016057580648c15c7f7cb9886ad4d6a1](https://github.com/dshkol/dshkol.github.io/tree/7da94409016057580648c15c7f7cb9886ad4d6a1), you haven't pushed the post `2017/08/30/starting-a-blog/index.html` to your Github repo yet. You should commit and push everything in the `public/` folder if you deploy via Github Pages.

As I wrote in [the **blogdown** book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/github-pages.html), you are recommended to deploy via Netlify instead of Github Pages, unless you can justify the latter (personally I don't see a single reason why one should still use Github Pages for building websites; here is [another shout-out](https://yihui.name/en/2017/06/netlify-instead-of-github-pages/)).

Comment: Thank you. This is an embarrassing miss; but, curious how this is happening. My workflow has been to specify the `publishDir=` to my github.io repository. The folder with the appropriate post content was generated into that repository, but was not pushed with everything else. As a test, I manually pushed the appropriate directory on its own, and that worked.

Is your preferred workflow to not use the `publishDir` parameter in the TOML, and just push the entire `public/` folder? I will check out Netlify deployment.

Finally, thank you for your help and many contributions to the R world.

Comment: It is fine to set `publishDir`. I have mentioned that in the same section in the book: https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/github-pages.html I don't know how you missed the HTML file, but with Netlify, you don't need to remember to push the publish directory. One fewer thing to remember == better.